# How to share state between runs of streaming jobs?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Spark streaming job triggered every day using Trigger.Once method due to business requirements.

```java
StreamingQuery query = processed
                       .writeStream()
                       .outputMode("append")
                       .format("parquet")
                       .option("path", resultPath)
                       .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLocationPathForDate)
                       .trigger(Trigger.Once())
                       .start();
```

I am using map `flatMapGroupsWithState` so that we can store state (`GroupState`) for grouped data.
Somewhere I read checkpointLocation should be different for every StreamingQuery. Therefore I use a checkpointLocation like this: `/path/to/nfs/checkpoint/<current date in format: yyyyMMdd>`

Every day, Spark job processes files in the folder `/path/to/data/<current date in format: yyyyMMdd>`

I want to access the state of the yesterday's Spark job since yesterday's data may contain relevant state that is needed in today's data.

However, Spark stores state data in checkpointLocation i.e `/path/to/nfs/checkpoint/<current date in format: yyyyMMdd>/<queryName>/state` so when different checkpointLocation is used, it is not possible to access it.

So, how can I access the GroupState data stored at checkpointLocation of previous Spark job? Is it OK to use same checkpointLocation for different StreamingQueries?

Edit:
I tried to use same checkpointLocation for yesterday's StreamingQuery and today's StreamingQuery and Spark restored state of yesterday's batch which is I want however is this documented anywhere? Is this expected behaviour or is misbehaving possible when same checkpointLocation is used between daily batches?

**Edit2:**

Data is stored at S3, in parquet format, path: `s3a://bucket/batchdata/year=2022/month=01/day=19/`

**Sample data for 2022-01-19:**

```
s3a://bucket/batchdata/year=2022/month=01/day=19/a.parquet
s3a://bucket/batchdata/year=2022/month=01/day=19/b.parquet
s3a://bucket/batchdata/year=2022/month=01/day=19/c.parquet
```

Data is read using Spark parquet readStream method:

```
// .parquet(...) is called for 2022-01-19

Dataset<Row> dataset = spark
                    .readStream()
                    .schema(PARQUET_SCHEMA)
                    .parquet("s3a://bucket/batchdata/year=2022/month=01/day=19/");


Dataset<Row> processed = dataset.groupByKey(keyFuncion,encoder)
                                .flatMapGroupsWithState(flatMapStateFunc, 
                                                        OutputMode.Append(),
                                                        stateEncoder,
                                                        outputEncoder,
                                                        GroupStateTimeout.ProcessingTimeTimeout());
                                

StreamingQuery query = processed.writeStream()
                               .outputMode("append")
                               .format("parquet")
                               .option("path", resultPath)
                               .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLocation)
                               .trigger(Trigger.Once())
                               .start();
query.awaitTermination();
```

Next day same job is run with next day's parquet files stored under:
`s3a://bucket/batchdata/year=2022/month=01/day=20/`

**Sample data for 2022-01-20:**

```
s3a://bucket/batchdata/year=2022/month=01/day=20/d.parquet
s3a://bucket/batchdata/year=2022/month=01/day=20/e.parquet
```

```
// .parquet(...) is called for 2022-01-20

Dataset<Row> dataset = spark
                    .readStream()
                    .schema(PARQUET_SCHEMA)
                    .parquet("s3a://bucket/batchdata/year=2022/month=01/day=20/");
                    
Dataset<Row> processed = dataset.groupByKey(keyFuncion,encoder)
                                .flatMapGroupsWithState(flatMapStateFunc, 
                                                        OutputMode.Append(),
                                                        stateEncoder,
                                                        outputEncoder,
                                                        GroupStateTimeout.ProcessingTimeTimeout());
                                

StreamingQuery query = processed.writeStream()
                               .outputMode("append")
                               .format("parquet")
                               .option("path", resultPath)
                               .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLocation)
                               .trigger(Trigger.Once())
                               .start();
query.awaitTermination();
```

Answer (score 1):

> how can I access the GroupState data stored at checkpointLocation of previous Spark job?

You should not. Technically, you could (with some extra coding) but there are so many things specific to the other query (e.g., stateful operator IDs) that you should take into account. Use at your own risk.

> Is it OK to use same checkpointLocation for different StreamingQueries?

No. You should not share the same `checkpointLocation` between different streaming queries. One is that they different with their operators so the numbers may not match and, even if they did, the sinks could be different and hence some data could get skipped (as already processed).

> I tried to use same checkpointLocation for yesterday's StreamingQuery and today's StreamingQuery and Spark restored state of yesterday's batch which is I want however is this documented anywhere? Is this expected behaviour or is misbehaving possible when same checkpointLocation is used between daily batches?

That's documented and that's exactly how `checkpointLocation` is supposed to work. It's the directory with the state of a streaming query at a given time.

Quoting [Recovering from Failures with Checkpointing](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#recovering-from-failures-with-checkpointing):

> In case of a failure or intentional shutdown, you can recover the previous progress and state of a previous query, and continue where it left off. This is done using checkpointing and write-ahead logs. You can configure a query with a checkpoint location, and the query will save all the progress information (i.e. range of offsets processed in each trigger) and the running aggregates (e.g. word counts in the quick example) to the checkpoint location. This checkpoint location has to be a path in an HDFS compatible file system, and can be set as an option in the DataStreamWriter when starting a query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I might not have described my problem clearly in the question. My use case is running same type of job / streaming query with different data which has the exact same semantics. Using Trigger.Once(), I process all currently available data, then next day, I use the same job with new data i.e For sake of simplicity you can assume like this function processAll(path/to/2023-01-19), then next day processAll(path/to/2023-01-20). For this use case, is it OK to use same checkpointLocation? Everyting is same for the StreamingQuery, only source folder is different next day.

Comment: _"For this use case, is it OK to use same checkpointLocation? "_ I'd say yes. But you also wrote _"only source folder is different next day"_ and that got me thinking about the source. What are the input sources? Can you share a physical plan of your query? (edit your question with the answers)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to cleanup physical plan in order to remove sensitive data, so I first tried to add sample input sources and sample code. Is this enough to clarify my use case or should I also add physical plan of my query?